# Create function inheriting koin component

Tags: kotlin, koin

I'm trying to simplify:

```
// Tag class with KoinComponent
class HelloApp : KoinComponent {

    // lazy inject dependency
    val helloService: HelloServiceImpl by inject()

    fun sayHello(){
        helloService.sayHello()
    }
}
```

to something like

```
fun sayHello() = koinComponent {
    val helloService: HelloServiceImpl by inject()
    helloService.sayHello()
}
```

Is it even possible that way, or I'm doomed with making a class with `invoke` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's doable:

First, let's define the service and the implementation:

```
interface HelloService {
    fun sayHello()
}

class HelloServiceImpl(private val name: String) : HelloService {
    override fun sayHello() {
        println("Hello, $name!")
    }
}
```

Pretty obvious, the service will say "Hello" to the person configured in its constructor.

Now, the `koinComponent` function:

```
fun <T> koinComponent(block: Koin.() -> T) {
    GlobalContext.get().koin.block()
}
```

Your function:

```
fun sayHello() = koinComponent {
    val helloService: HelloServiceImpl by inject()

    helloService.sayHello()
}
```

And the usage:

```
fun main() {
    startKoin {
        modules(listOf(
            module {
                single { HelloServiceImpl("majkrzak") }
            }
        ))
    }

    sayHello()
}
```

Output: `Hello, majkrzak!`

It's all very simple: in order to be able to use the [`inject` delegate](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/reference/index.html#_retrieving_definitions_with_get_inject), you need a Koin context. Actually, the way `KoinComponent` works is by using the `GlobalContext`:

```
interface KoinComponent {
    fun getKoin(): Koin = GlobalContext.get().koin
}

inline fun <reified T> KoinComponent.inject(
        qualifier: Qualifier? = null,
        noinline parameters: ParametersDefinition? = null
): Lazy<T> =
        getKoin().inject(qualifier, parameters)
```

So, why not do the same? We declare the `koinComponent` function so that it's `block` argument is called with a `Koin` receiver and use that global koin instance implicitly.

We can make it more reusable by using default values:

```
fun <T> koinComponent(koin: Koin = GlobalContext.get().koin, block: Koin.() -> T) {
    koin.block()
}
```

Now I have a question to you: why do you need that?

Comment: Mostly experimenting with Kotllin. Currently I have implemented simplle service in form:
```class Query : KoinComponent {
    private val client: HttpClient by inject()
    suspend operator fun invoke(query: String) =
        client.post<Response>(url) {
            body = query
        }
}
``` and was wondering if i can do it a bit more simpllified.

Comment: I've just realized that it is a workaround, is there any legit method?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It works **exactly** like `KoinComponent`.